# Android http request synchron with Volley

Tags: android

I write code to make a request http to server:

```
public void reqCategory() {
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    String url = "http://myaddress/getdata.php";
    StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

            //Json Parse
            try {

                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);

                catList.clear();

                for (int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    catList.add(jsonObject.getString("categoria"));

                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        }

    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d("Error -> ", error.toString());


        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() { //nessun parametro
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            //no param at moment
            return params;
        }
    };
    queue.add(postRequest);
}
```

I declare:

```
List<String> catList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

in my onCreate I have:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_comanda);

    reqCategory();

    for (String s : catList) {
        Log.d("Categoria -> ", s);
    }
}
```

This should be fill the List catList with values from reqCategory(), but the for loop doesnt show the values, because the request is asyncron.

How I can make a syncron request so I have the values in catList after the reqCategory() call and I can see the values from loop for.

Thank you.

Comment: what is `synchron request`?

Comment: on request the app wait until the request end. I think.

Answer (score 0):

try some minor edit in your code

```
for (int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String Temp = new 
                catList.add(new String(jsonObject.getString("categoria")));

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have networking blocking UI thread on Android. All networking must be on separate thread, therefore you need to refactor your code to be like, i.e.:

```
onCreate() {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_comanda);

  reqCategory();
}
```

where `reqCategory()` must spawn i.e. AsyncTask for the networking. Once AsyncTask is done you can executre your loop in its `onPostExecute()` (or in `odInBackground()` if you do not need to touch UI widgets).